# rails migration partial index's where not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations, partial-index

i have a rails migration script:

```
add_index :site_tracking_codes, [:site_id, :is_published], where: "is_published IS TRUE", unique: true
```

but it generates the index like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_site_tracking_codes_on_site_id_and_is_published ON public.site_tracking_codes USING btree (site_id, is_published);
```

without the where condition.
rails version: ~> 4.2.11. postgreSQL 9.6 DB

Comment: I wonder if you want `where: "is_published"` instead of `where: "is_published IS TRUE"`. A stab in the dark.

Comment: The only thing I can see in the docs is `unique: true` is before the `where: ".."`

Comment: @jvillian, @ben-trewern tried the `where: "is_published"` and` unique: true` before `where` .. same results.When i run the migration script this is the console output
`add_index(:site_tracking_codes, [:site_id, :is_published], {:unique=>true, :where=>"is_published"})
   -> 0.0056s`
but the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` is missing the where condition